# JQuery: removeAttr does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to remove an attribute of img. Here you can see my codes :

```
 $("#zoom_05").removeAttr('data - zoom - image');
```

And my img :

```
   <img id="zoom_05" src="http://localhost:3192/ProductImages/Small/093.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://localhost:3192/ProductImages/Larges/093.jpg" />
```

I can remove src attribute but I can not `remove data-zoom-image` attribute. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I'm assuming that the additional spaces in the removeAttr are just a typo? 'data - zoom - image' versus 'data-zoom-image'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using whitespaces when you shouldn't:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#zoom_05").removeAttr('data-zoom-image');
});
```

In case you don't believe me... :) http://jsfiddle.net/7ZTkC/

Comment: I deleted whitespaces but the same result..
 $("#zoom_05").removeAttr('data-zoom-image');

Comment: As you can check in my fiddle. This works properly. You might be doing something wrong. Are you including it on the `$(document).ready(function(){` ?

Comment: Yes I do it in   $(document).ready(function ()

Comment: @cagin are you creating the image dynamically ?

Comment: I set some default values to attributes. I want to change src and data-zoom-image attributes in document.ready.

Comment: I changed my code with this:     
 $("#zoom_05").attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/300x300');
      $("#zoom_05").attr('data-zoom-image', 'http://placehold.it/600x600'); But it is same result. I can not change data-zoom-image attribute.

Comment: @cagin as I said, you might be doing something else wrong. My code works perfectly as you can see in the fiddle.